# How to print the contents of array in x86 assembly language?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, tasm

I am trying to code bubble sort in assembly language ( 8086 ).

Here is the code :

```
DATA SEGMENT
STRING1 DB 99H,12H,56H,45H,36H
DATA ENDS

CODE SEGMENT
ASSUME CS:CODE,DS:DATA
START: MOV AX,DATA
MOV DS,AX

MOV CH,04H

UP2: MOV CL,04H
LEA SI,STRING1



UP1: MOV AL,[SI]
MOV BL,[SI+1]
CMP AL,BL
JC DOWN
MOV DL,[SI+1]
XCHG [SI],DL
MOV [SI+1],DL

DOWN: INC SI
DEC CL
JNZ UP1
DEC CH
JNZ UP2

INT 3

CODE ENDS
END START
```

The code is executing just fine without any error but I'm not able to think how I should print the contents of the array.

I tried debugging and looked at the memory locations at which the array is stored. The memory locations show the correct output but I want to print the array contents before and after the sorting.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45904076/547981)

Comment: Do you want to see the array hexadecimal (12,36,45,56,99) or decimal (18,54,69,86,153)?